# In double slit experiment how do we observe electrons near slit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, electrons, double-slit-experiment

If we observe the electron near the slit, does it produces two bands instead of interference pattern. Also how do we observe electron. Is it by producing electric field. Also does double slit experiment only works with coherent sources of light or all sources? What do you think about the below explanation of wave. http://www.bioinsilico.blogspot.in/2015/03/intelligence-and-in-search-of.html In the figure, the length of up and down represents amplitude and the speed of up and down represents wavelength. If we are observing electrons by producing electric field, won't it disturb the wave nature of electrons.

Answer (score 1):

> If we observe the electron, does it produces two bands instead of interference pattern. Also how do we observe electron.

Depending on the distance between the two slits, there is interference. If the slits are too far appart with respect to the momentum of the electrons ( heisenberg uncertainty) then two blobs will appear. [Here is an one electron at the time experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles) with electrons:

[image: singleelectron ds]

> Is it by producing electric field.

In the above experiment the electron hits a screen and leave a point on the screen ( electromagnetic interactions with the chemicals of the screen are involved)

> Also does double slit experiment only works with coherent sources of light or all sources?

It works one particle ( photon or electron or ..) at a time. Coherence, is useful so that the points do not overlap and erase the image.

> What do you think about the below explanation of wave.

Not  relevant to the real physics at the elementary particle level.

> If we are observing electrons by producing electric field, won't it disturb the wave nature of electrons.

The wave nature of the electron or any other massive particle is not a wave in energy or mass or charge. It is a sinusoidal probability of interaction wave, the probability of the electron being observed at (x,y) at the z of the screen. One electron shows no interference because probability is a distribution from many instances, and that is what is seen in the experiment.